# Integrate webform submissions with Google sheet

Tags: webforms, 9

How do I integrate webform submissions with google sheet in Drupal 9? I've found a way using Zapier but that allows only a limited number of submissions per month. Is there any way I can achieve it programatically to overcome this limitation?

Comment: Does this module helps https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_googlesheets ?

Comment: I've tried this module but doesn't support drupal 9. I've tried manually placing the zip folder and altering the core_version_requirement. But the when clicked on Google sheets in Add Handler under Webform Email/Handlers for the webform. Nothing happens. But it works on drupal 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out! Posting my solution here for anyone trying to integrate google sheets with webform.
Enable the Google API PHP client module and follow the setup steps provided in the [Documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/google-api-php-client) to setup your API.

Create a custom module and place this code in the .module file

```
    function hook_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id){
        if ($form['#webform_id'] == 'your-webform-id') {
            // add an AJAX callback to the form submission
            $form['actions']['submit']['#ajax'] = array(
                'callback' => 'processFormSubmission',
                'event' => 'click',
                'progress' => [
                    'type' => 'none',
                ],
            );
        }
    
    }

    function processFormSubmission(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state){
        //Get the values from webform to store it in google sheet
        $first_name = $form_state->getValue('first_name');
        $last_name = $form_state->getValue('last_name');
        $email = $form_state->getValue('email');
        // Load the account
        $google_api_client = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('google_api_client')->load(your_client_id);
        // Get the service.
        $googleService = \Drupal::service('google_api_client.client');
        // Apply the account to the service
        $googleService->setGoogleApiClient($google_api_client);
        // Fetch Sheets object.
        $object = $googleService->getServiceObjects();
        // $object['sheets'] is a object of Google_Service_Sheets
        $sheets = $object['sheets'];
        $single_sheet = $sheets->spreadsheets_values;
        $spreadsheetID = "your spreadsheet id form url";
        $range = 'Sheet1';//Correct here for your sheet name
        $values = [
            [$first_name,$last_name,$email],
        ];
        $body = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange([
            'values' => $values
        ]);
        $params = [
            'valueInputOption' => 'RAW',
        ];
        $insert = [
            "insertDataOption"=> "INSERT_ROWS",
        ];
        $single_sheet_update = $sheets->spreadsheets_values->append($spreadsheetID, $range, $body, $params, $insert);
    }
```

I've used hook form alter to insert an ajax call on submit and when submit button is clicked, I get the values from the webform and an API call is made to the Sheets API and store the values in the google sheet.